# Continuous dependence of maximal interval on right hand side for ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Let $f,f_n\colon\mathbb{R}\times(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ be local Lipschitz continuous functions and assume they form the right-hand-side of some ordinary differential equation's $\dot{x} = f(t,x)$ and $\dot{x_n} = f_n(t,x_n)$ with initial values $(t_n^0,x_n^0)$ and $(t^0,x^0)$ respectively. Moreover, let us assume that $f_n$ converges to $f$ (in some sense) and $(t_n^0,x_n^0)\to(t^0,x^0)$. From standard theory on ordinary differential equations we know that for each ode, we find a maximal time interval $(t_n^\text{min},t_n^\text{max})$ and $(t^\text{min},t^\text{max})$, respectively, where our solutions uniquely exists.

My question is, when do we have $t_n^\text{max}\to t^\text{max}$?

Concrete, I need the result for $f,f_n\colon\mathbb{R}_+\times(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}_+$ with $f_n\to f$ uniformly on all compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}_+\times(0,1)$. Intuitively, I think this should work as the solutions stay close to each other the whole time. Do you maybe have some literature for such questions?

Comment: I believe the convergence is true even under pointwise convergence of coefficients, if the local Lipschitz continuity is uniform in $n$. Otherwise, with your assumption this should be true if the Lipschitz continuity is non-uniform. But I am not really a specialist in ode's, unfortunately.

Comment: The answers so far show that $t_n^\text{max}\to t^\text{max}$ does not hold in general and that we can in general only hope for $t^\text{max}\le\liminf t_n^\text{max}$ (see@Julián Aguirre). It is still an open question, under which conditions the limit holds. Are there some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 3.2 in [P. Hartman's Ordinary Differential Equations](https://books.google.es/books/about/Ordinary_differential_equations.html?id=NEkkJ93O9okC&hl=en), is what you are looking for. The result says
$$
\limsup t^{\text{min}}_n\le t^{\text{min}}<t^{\text{max}}\le\liminf t^{\text{max}}_n.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Do you know if one can also get an actual equality under some stronger assumptions? Is there an easy counterexample for the equality under my assumptions?

Comment: All examples I have tried give equality, but I have no proof that ir is always so.

Comment: I also tried a bit but as for you, my examples always yield equality. Do you think that it is actually an open question? Standard textbooks usually do not even state the inequality.

Comment: Since it is stated as a Theorem in Hartman's book, I presume that inequality is possible. I have an example that does not apply at your situation, but to a domain like $\mathbb{R}\times(0,1)\setminus\{(1,1/2)\}$.

Comment: I would be interested in your example. As I am new on SE, I am not sure: would it be possible to state it as an answer here? Moreover, I tried to extend the result in Hartman's book using a result for continuous dependence of the solution on the right hand side (e.g. Walter theorem 13.2) instead of his Arzela argument. I think it goes through. May I show a proof here as an answer?

Comment: This is the example: $f(t,x)=0$, $\Omega=\mathbb{R}\times(0,1)\setminus\{(1,1/2)\}$. Then the solution with $x(0)=1/2$ is defined on $(-\infty,1)$, and the solutions with $x(0)\ne0$ on $\mathbb{R}$. I think it is appropriate for you to write an answer, or at least give the reference.

Comment: Your example looks nice. Thanks for that. I also found a small mistake in my proof. Sorry. But nevertheless, I think it should be possible under some additional assumptions. So if you have any further ideas, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In general, convergence of $t_n^\text{max}\to t^\text{max}$ is not true. The most one can hope for is stated in [this answer by Julián Aguirre](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1470360/257844). Consider the right hand sides (for $n>2$)
$$f,f_n\colon\mathbb{R}\times(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}\\
f_n(t,x)=a_n\cos(t),\\f(t,x)=a\cos(t)$$
where $a_n=\frac{1}{2}−\frac{1}{n}$ and $a=\frac{1}{2}$. Clearly, $f,f_n$ are Lipschitz and we have uniform convergence for $n\to\infty$. Let $(t_n^0,x_n^0)=(t^0,x^0)=(0,\frac{1}{2})$. Then these ODEs are solved by
$$x_n\colon\mathbb{R}\to(0,1),\quad x_n(t)=a_n\sin(t)+\frac{1}{2},\\
x\colon\Bigl(−\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigr)\to(0,1),\quad x(t)=a\sin(t)+\frac{1}{2}.$$
Hence, the times of explosion are $t_n^\text{max}=\infty$ and $t^\text{max}=\frac{\pi}{2}$, which clearly do not converge.